# Notification not reaching iOS device even though send(message) is successful

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, notifications, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to build a Firebase cloud function to send notification. I am able to use the FCM token to send a notification directly to the iOS device using the console and my iOS device displays the notificatino. However, the device is not receiving the notification using the cloud function below, even though the FCM token is the same and the send(message) call is successful. Am I missing something?

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var db = admin.firestore();

exports.requestCreated = functions.firestore
.document('users/{userId}')
.onWrite((change, context) => {
  const createdBy = context.params.userId;
  console.log("Request created by ",createdBy);
  var userRef = db.collection('users').doc(createdBy);
  return userRef.get().then(doc => {
  console.log('Data: ',doc.data());
  console.log('FCM token: ',doc.data().fcmToken);

      // This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
      var registrationToken = doc.data().fcmToken;

      // See documentation on defining a message payload.
      var message = {
        data: {
          score: '850'
        },
        token: registrationToken
      };

      // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
      // registration token.
      admin.messaging().send(message)
        .then((response) => {
          // Response is a message ID string.
          console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('Error sending message:', error);
        });
  });
});
```

Comment: r u implemented didReceiveRemoteNotification and also go capabilities and enable remote notification in background modes

Comment: Have you tried `sendToDevice()` method?

Comment: has your problem been solved?

Comment: sendToDevice helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Add notification in message payload

```
var message = {
        data: {
          score: '850'
        },
        notification: {
          title: "",
          body: ""
        }
        token: registrationToken
      };
```

Your code normally workin Android. in IOS you need to attach notification in message payload & also use sendToDevice(). Try this one. you have to get the score using from this payload. will be work

Comment: Thank you. That helped. Unfortunately I am still battling with displaying the notification on the device when app is in foreground.